# Merge two ready() function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ready

I have two `$(document).ready(function($)` function in my HTML file . Now since there are two `ready()` functions,only one executes ! Since I dont have much idea about jQuery,I am unable to merge them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function($){

        $('#mega-1').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'show',
            direction: 'right'
        });
        $('#mega-2').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'slow',
            effect: 'fade',
            direction: 'left'
        });
        $('#mega-3').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '4',
            speed: 'slow',
            effect: 'slide',
            direction: 'right'
        });
        $('#mega-4').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'slide',
            direction: 'left'
        });

    });
    </script>
```

jQuery function 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just add the statement from the second ready() function to the first.

Comment: Does the JS have to be inline? Could you move it to an external JS file and reference it?

Comment: Well something is wrong, because all ready functions should fire... I've used loads of document ready functions all over the place without issue.

Comment: It doesn't execute *just one* they both work unless one has some error.

Comment: And there is no reason why two `$(document).ready()` functions should not work. The problem must be somewhere else!

Comment: jQuery will execute as many DOM-ready callbacks as you bind, so if one isn't firing (are you sure?) there must be an error getting logged. And yes, your JS should be in its own file, rather than in your HTML.

Comment: I tried removing one by one ready and the corresponding jQuery pluging worked.

Comment: They WILL fire in the order that they are bound. Just stating the obvious.

Comment: Did you include jQuery more than once? Did you try to change the order in which you include both plug-ins?

Comment: All your functions defined inside $(document).ready() will be executed - you either have errors or they work but don't do what you are expecting - debug them with firebug or the built in chrome/opera/ie 9 debugger

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Page Title</title>

<script src="some_javascript_file.js"></script>
<script src="another_js_file.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML HERE -->


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery_plugin_1.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery_plugin_2.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){ // remap $ to jQuery

    $(function(){
        $('#mega-1').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'show',
            direction: 'right'
        });
        $('#mega-2').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'slow',
            effect: 'fade',
            direction: 'left'
        });
        $('#mega-3').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '4',
            speed: 'slow',
            effect: 'slide',
            direction: 'right'
        });
        $('#mega-4').dcVerticalMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '3',
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'slide',
            direction: 'left'
        });


        // =====================================

        $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);

    });

})(jQuery);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```